# Javascript page load event

Tags: javascript

Is there no way to run a `function` in JavaScript when a user navigates to a new page at a different URL and the new page loads?

`window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function)` only works on the current page. What are my options to execute a `function` on a new page?

Comment: Every script tag with a valid `src` to a `.js` file or with JavaScript inside of it will be executed on every page you put it on. So basically JavaScript will run on every page it is present. But it might help if you give some more explanation on your goal.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you saying when a page loads for the first time on a site that you own?

Comment: Can't you add the JavaScript you want to run on the new page to load instead of the previous page? Or must it only run if the user navigates from a specific page? In which case you could check the [`Referer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header on the server for the page the user is navigating from.

Comment: This needs more information. The answer will largely depend on the owner of the page, the navigation method, the application context, ect. For example your own website using popstate to navigate a spa, a user hard navigating away to another page on your domain, an extension watching a page, ect ect ect. All of these have different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

this will do:

```
window.addEventListener("load", yourFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on your access to the other page's source-code. If it's in your hand, then you can create a load event, like @Besufkad Menji suggested. Otherwise, if you do not have access to the other page, then your possibilities are limited

## iframe

You can load the other page in an `iframe` and have an `onload` for that `iframe`.

## Browser extension

You can implement a browser extension which will achieve the behavior you want.

## In general

You cannot really run a code for a user visiting a site you do not have access to. The user did not allow you, nor the other site, which means that the behavior you intend to achieve will not really be available anytime soon.